# Connection between image space and Hough space?

Tags: polar-coordinates, image-processing, computer-vision

The other day I got very interested in learning about Hough Transform that is used to detect edges in images.

After going through [OpenCV documentation](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d9/db0/tutorial_hough_lines.html), I still couldn't piece together an understanding for myself.

So I found this great video that provides a (very welcome) visual example of the interaction between the image space and the Hough space.

However before jumping straight to polar coordinates with rho and theta, a simpler example is shown: the relationship between X and Y; and a and b (the intercept and the slope).

**Can somebody explain why a single Xi,Yi translates to a whole line in a/b space (if looking at cartesian coordinates)?**

([x/y space to a/b space graphs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F4ZPG.png))

By the way, here's the [complete yt video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4zHbI-fFIlI&ab_channel=ThalesSehnK%C3%B6rting) that I am referring to in the snippet above.

I think after getting this down pat, the general translation between image space and Hough space will come easier to me.

Thank you for helping.

Comment: The diagram does not seem to be related to polar coordinates.

Comment: @kiyanuDevs Something's wrong with diagram you attached. A general tip, referencing something is ok, but if you refer to a written material rather than a video, its more encouraged.

Comment: As said at once in the Open CV document, there are **two types** of Hough transforms: you have chosen to take the one which is wrt cartesian coordinates. My experience is that the other one (wrt polar coordinates) is more appropriate : in particular, it allows a thorough treatment of the special kind of duality attached to this transform.

Comment: Regarding closing this question, I watched the video linked in the question before coming back and answering, so I would say that the question is not very well posed since it required me to watch the video. However, the misunderstanding of the poster seems very simple to resolve as I've tried to point out in my brief answer. I'm not sure this should be closed but hopefully this brief answer will be of some use to the questioner.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The equation $y=ax+b$ has various solutions in $a$ and $b$. Given only one point, $(x_i,y_i)$, we don't know what the values of $a$ and $b$ are, but we can constrain them to lie on a line given by $b=x_i-ay_i$. The point to note here is that we've gone from regarding $x$ and $y$ as variables to regarding $a$ and $b$ as variables.

The transform in question in the video looks at all pairs of points in an image in a quest to find entire sets of points which all lie on a particular line, in other words where the $a$ and $b$ values for many points coincide.